# Is this 'nor' a short form of 'nor knowing'?

Tags: conjunctions, ellipsis

> A breeze ruffled the neat hedges of Privet Drive, which lay silent and tidy under the inky sky, the very last place you would expect astonishing things to happen. Harry Potter rolled over inside his blankets without waking up. One small hand closed on the letter beside him and he slept on, not knowing he was special, not knowing he was famous, not knowing he would be woken in a few hours' time by Mrs. Dursley's scream as she opened the front door to put out the milk bottles, **nor** that he would spend the next few weeks being prodded and pinched by his cousin Dudley... He couldn't know that at this very moment, people meeting in secret all over the country were holding up their glasses and saying in hushed voices: "To Harry Potter -- the boy who lived!"
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is *nor* the short form of "nor knowing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a strange way of asking the question. The last part of the sentence could have been written as:

> *not knowing he was special, that he was famous, that he would be woken in a few hours' time by Mrs. Dursley's scream as she opened the front door to put out the milk bottles, that he would spend the next few weeks being prodded and pinched by his cousin Dudley*.

Which is to say there needn't actually be any *nor* in the first place, nor any constant repetition of *not knowing*. It's not that *nor* is "short for" anything in that sense - it's just that some words which could have been repeated are elided (missed out because they're obvious). As OED says, *nor* is a *conjunction*...

> used before the second or further of two or more alternatives, normally to negate each.

---

It's also worth pointing out that the sentence *could* have ended...

> *...put out the milk bottles, **nor knowing** that he would spend the next few weeks being prodded and pinched by his cousin Dudley*.

...where obviously *nor* isn't short for *"not knowing"*

---

TL;DR: *nor* itself isn't really "short for" anything. It's just a variant of *not / not either / neither*. But because it's used to introduce *second or subsequent alternatives*, it often occurs in "list" contexts where the items in the list may be similar/related, *and thus contain **repeated elements** which may be **deleted** (by [ellipsis](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=ellipsis&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=JA44UerBDYmeO679gOAE&ved=0CDIQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=a406911aeac3db44&biw=1319&bih=897))*.

Comment: @WendiKidd: Yeah - it's the only important bit really. I'd already written the first sentence of the last paragraph before I wrote anything else, but it wasn't until I was just about to post the whole answer that it finally dawned on me why OP might think *nor* is a word that could *in and of itself* be said to "stand for" something longer.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, the implied verb is *knowing*. This doesn't mean that *nor* is a short form for *nor knowing*.

Comment: I'd just like to add for the benefit of future readers that this is true only in this specific case--as the sentence construction has already said "not knowing" multiple times, knowing is indeed the implied verb here. That isn't *always* what "nor" means, though; it depends upon context.  +1 :)

Comment: Of course: An implied verb depends from the context.